# Printing inputted string in assembly language

Tags: string, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I wanna print what the user inputted first. However, it displays the converted uppercase already before the result.

Here's my code:

```
  org 100h


BEGIN:
          LEA DX, DASH1          
          MOV AH, 9
          INT 21H
          
          LEA DX,LOWERCASE
          MOV AH,09H
          INT 21H

          LEA SI,STR1
          MOV AH,01H
              
              
READ:
          INT 21H
          MOV BL,AL 

          CMP AL,0DH
          JE  DISPLAY

          XOR AL,20H
          MOV [SI],AL
          INC SI

          JMP READ        
          

DISPLAY:               
          MOV AL,"$"
          MOV [SI],AL                    

          LEA DX,UPPERCASE
          MOV AH,09H
          INT 21H   
                 
          LEA DX, STR1
          MOV AH, 09H
          INT 21H 
          
          MOV DL, BH  ; space
          MOV AH, 02H
          INT 21H               
          
          LEA DX, UPPERCASE_          
          MOV AH, 9
          INT 21H
          
          LEA DX,STR1
          MOV AH,09H
          INT 21H 
          
          LEA DX, DASH2          
          MOV AH, 9
          INT 21H

          MOV AH,4CH
          INT 21H
         
  ret
   
    LOWERCASE  DB 0DH,0AH,0AH, "   Input a 5-letter string: $"
    UPPERCASE DB  0DH,0AH, "   The uppercase equivalent of $"
    UPPERCASE_ DB "is $"   
    DASH1 DB 0AH,0DH, " ================================================================= $"  
    DASH2 DB 0AH,0AH,0DH, " ================================================================= $"
    STR1 DB 255 DUP(?)
```

Output:

`Input a 5-letter string: asdfg`

`The uppercase equivalent of ASDFG is ASDFG`

```
                             ^ i want this part to print as `asdfg`
```

making it `The uppercase equivalent of asdfg is ASDFG`

P.S. also, how do I make the string limited to 5 only? Its because the string a user can input can exceed more than 5. Any tips?

==============================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying strings `UPPERCASE`, `STR1`, `UPPERCASE_`,`STR1`, respectively, no wonder that `STR1` remains the same. You need to reserve one more string `STRorig` where you should store the obtained character before its case is changed.
You can use `DI` to address `STRorig` and then perform `STOSB` for saving original  `AL` to `ES:DI` and incrementing `DI`.

When you want to limit the size of input string, compare `SI` with `STR1 + 5` and if it's above, act as if `AL` was equal to `0DH`.